# Variable return types of DecimalField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, floating-point, decimal

I have a model thats something like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    value_a = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=4, max_digits=20)
    value_b = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=4, max_digits=20)
    value_c = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=4, max_digits=20)
```

Now suppose that I have the following item:

```
a = Item()
a.value_a = 1.20
a.value_b = 2
a.value_c = Decimal('20.20')
a.save()
```

When I access the object (after retrieving from DB) values I get:

```
a.value_a = 1.2 <float>
a.value_b = 2 <int>
a.value_c = Decimal('20.20')
```

Notice that my DB data type may vary from one to another.

Why DecimalField does that? Can't I get the values always as python Decimal?

Comment: `Decimal('20.20')` is a python Decimal. What value are you expecting?

Comment: Well, only 'c' returns Decimal.

Answer (score 0):

If you `save()` each of the created `Item`s after changing the `value`'s value, Django will convert them into Python Decimals.

```
a = Item()
a.value = 1.20
a.save()
item_a = Item.objects.get(id=a.id)
print(item_a.value)  # will be Decimal('1.20')
```

Comment: This is not correct for all cases. I have an Oracle DB in my production env., while for testing I have a postgres DB, by recovering objects from both DBs the values aren't always the same type, mainly due to the data type defined on each DB.
Look, if in the DB the column is defined as an integer data type the python object field won't be Decimal but int.

Comment: Right, if the field is defined as DecimalField it would return a Decimal, and if defined as a IntegerField it would return an int. 
Are you saying that Django returns an integer for DecimalFields if using an Oracle DB?

Comment: It depends on the data type defined on the Oracle DB. If the data type on the DB is integer, when I access the DecimalField value its an <int>.